# I2C, DCMI stops working after waking up from STOP mode in stm32f4

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

The `I2C` and `DCMI` stops working on my custom board after wake up from `STOP` mode. I deinitialize GPIO's before going into `STOP` mode. After wake up from `STOP` for `I2C` I always get `HAL_BUSY` for both read and write while for camera on `DCMI` I get some random data instead of jpeg image. But if I don't deinitialize GPIO's then everything works fine without any problem but there is higher power consumption in `STOP` mode. Following is my code for GPIO's deinitialization

```
void MX_GPIO_Deinit()
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Disable GPIOs clock */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_DISABLE();
}
```

Is there any to reset `I2C` and `DCMI` properly after waking from `STOP` mode? Calling functions `MX_I2C2_Init()` and `MX_DCMI_Init()` doesn't work. What is the proper way for handling this and make `I2C` and `DCMI` work?

Answer (score 0):

**Peripherals can be reset using the `RCC`** (Reset and Clock Control).

Find the bits corresponding to the peripherals to be reset in the `RCC...RSTR` registers, set them to 1, and clear them to 0. E.g. for DCMI, it would be

```
RCC->AHB2RSTR |= RCC_AHB2RSTR_DCMIRST;
RCC->AHB2RSTR &= ~RCC_AHB2RSTR_DCMIRST;
```

HAL provides some macros that save you the need to look up the register names, like

```
__HAL_RCC_DCMI_FORCE_RESET();
__HAL_RCC_DCMI_RELEASE_RESET();
```

You can find the register bits and the macros for the I2C peripheral in the Reference Manual, or in the HAL headers.